# Electron print to pdf selection only

Tags: javascript, pdf, electron

I need to export to PDF in electron, but not the whole page but only a section (an HTML node would be great).
With the whole page it works fine.
I see an option in the documentation: printSelectionOnly:

> printSelectionOnly Boolean (optional) - Whether to print selection
> only.

[Electron docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsprinttopdfoptions)

But I don't know if it is true how it would work.
How do I make that selection? Could it be an HTML node?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

The printSelectionOnly option is to select only the focused content in the window to print / export to PDF.

This answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

The printSelectionOnly option prints only what has been selected in the page.

What they mean by "selection only" is all the elements in the page that are currently highlighted in blue and that you would be able to copy using ctrl+c.

[Image of selected text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdIFh.png)

To make it an HTML node, you need to create a range object. Then, select the node using the range object. This will allow you to only print one node of the page.

```js
function selectDiv() {
  selectElementById("frame");
}

function selectChildDiv() {
  selectElementById("childDiv");
}

function selectElementById(id) {
  let element = document.getElementById(id); 
  // Create the range object
  let range = new Range();
  // Select the node using the range object
  range.setStart(element, 0);
  range.setEndAfter(element, 0);
  // Apply the range
  document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  document.getSelection().addRange(range);
  // This is where you would call the printToPDF
}
```

```css
button, #frame {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px fuchsia;
    padding: 5px;
}

i {
  position: relative;
}

i::after {
  content: "I can not be selected";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%; right: 0%;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: small;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="selectDiv()">Select parent div</button>
<button onclick="selectChildDiv()">Select child div</button>
<p>Element before div</p>
<div id="frame">
  Inner Text
  <p>Element inside div</p>
  <i>Note : Unselectable elements like pseudo elements won't be selected.</i>
  <div id="childDiv">Div inside div</div>
</div>
<p>Element after div</p>
```